# How to disable the annoying NetBeans auto-suggest while typing

Tags: html, netbeans, netbeans-8

When I am typing in NetBeans 8.2, whether it is a HTML paragraph or something like an input field, this annoying auto-suggest feature keeps on popping up. It is really annoying when I try to press enter to start a new line as it will insert a load of code when I press enter, since 'Button' is automatically highlighted.

I've included a screenshot of the problem below...

[image: The bit that isn't blurred out is the problem. I have blurred the rest of the page since it contains some personal information and profane language.]

How can I disable this autocorrect feature. I don't want to disable autoorrect for PHP or when actually setting up a HTML tag (*so I want to use it in a situation like this... `<input type="autocorrect displays here" />`, but not when typing anything else*).

Sorry if I haven't explained myself very well, I can't really think of a good way to describe my problem. Please, leave a commend if you need to know more.

Thanks :)

PS: I can't find any other answers on the internet because I don't know what this is called, since I want this specific auto-suggest to disappear, so please direct me to another answer and I'll delete this question if the answer is appropriate.

PPS: I think the palette may have something to do with it but I can't be sure.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I finally found the solution for this annoying problem:

Simply go to Tools/Palette/Code Clips and remove everything from Palette (all folders and items).

Now the problem is gone!

Comment: THANK U :D
That's some determination!

Comment: Everyone needs to up vote this question and answer please!  This is golden.

Comment: I don't know who decided to include this feature but its seriosly breaking the use of netbeans. I couldn't even use my tab key to indent my code, because this box would popup and the second time i pressed tab it would do all kinds of horrible stuff. THANKS for the solution!

Comment: For me, this behavior made troubles in Laravel blade views, even made NB unresponsive if I went panic. +1 for the solution.

Comment: The stupidest thing is you actually HAVE to remove the entries. It is not enough to just untick them.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Netbeans crashes on me about four times a day or so because it's trying to google the whole internet for every third verb when I type a docblock comment in a css or javascript file. Optional bells and whistles should never be mandatory or on by default in well written software.

Comment: Thanks! I also tried deselecting them, but now that I have removed them they finally don't show up anymore :)

Comment: Happy to have found your question in Google with this quite-hard to explain issue. Question though, it seems the first correct answer came from the guy named Niko but he's answer wasn't selected?

Answer (score 13):

If you go into NetBeans > Tools > Options > Editor > Code Completion, you can check or uncheck "Auto Popup Completion Window" for whatever Languages you want.

[image: NetBeans AutoComplete Checkbox]

If you move over to the Code Templates tab, you can also customize the specific autocomplete rules for each Language. That way, you can leave certain ones in that you find helpful and remove ones that you find bothersome.

[image: NetBeans AutoComplete Customize]

Comment: This doesn't work.  I have just run into this problem myself, and if I disable "auto popup completion window" for HTML code only, it still appears.

Comment: I'm sorry it didn't work for you, but this worked for me. Did you try clearing out the specific autocomplete rules? Do you have any additional extensions that may be performing autocomplete?

Comment: Nope.  I'm using a vanilla install, and I've tried pretty much every combination of rules and checkboxes I can think of.  The only solution that seems to work is to disable autocomplete for everything.

Comment: This is how I expected it to work, too, but it doesn't. For me this started when upgrading from 8.0.2 to 8.2. Disabling "Auto Popup Completion Window" for "All Languages" does work, but it cripples a core IDE feature.

Comment: I had this stupid English words hinting going on for every little thing i typed and it was more of a nuisance than help. And I tried disabling the English spell check dictionary plugin but didn't help, so this was the only solution that helped. Also If I require code completion I can manually bring in the suggestions by using `ctrl` + `space`.

Comment: This has consistently failed to work on fresh installs of every version of Netbeans since 7.2. As we are coming into the 9.0 beta, it still fails to work frequently.

Comment: Works in Apache Netbeans 12.1. Solution with palette does not.

Comment: I can confirm that this is the right solution for Netbeans 12, thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Today I finally had enought of these *** autocompletes in my *** code.

Found my way thru Google to this question and found no comfort from the answers.

But this is how I did it:

1. Open Code Clips -manager (Tools > Palette > Code Clips)

[image]

2. Select all HTML-related and click "Remove"

[image]

3. Profit

Answer (score 4):

2021. Apache Netbeans 12.1.

Palette > Code Clips > Remove  -- does not work.

NetBeans  > Tools  > Options  > Editor  > Code Completion  >  Disable "Auto popup completion window" -- does work.

Comment: It doesn't work if you want just remove HTML and keep PHP for exemple.

Answer (score 1):

In **NetBeans 12**, disabling the Auto Popup Completion Window option for **HTML** does not solve the problem when editing PHP files, the popup shows up whenever Tab is pressed in HTML portions of code.

The solution is to keep the Auto Popup Completion Window active for **All Languages**, then switch to the **Code Templates** tab, select Language: **HTML**, remove all templates from the list, and voilá. No more HTML popup suggestions, anywhere, ever. Only the good old PHP suggestions will remain active.

Comment: This solve the problem if you edit html in .php files