# NetBeans - How to stop annoying "insert button" popup from showing?

Tags: netbeans

If I hit tab multiple times to indent something, then I always get an anoying window showing up:

[image]

This is extremly annoying, how can I stop this?

UPDATE: I use Netbeans 8.2.

It seems to happen in `.html` files and also in blade templates but not in pure .php files.

[image]

I have to write something, if I then press tab a dropdown will appear sometimes if I then press tab again, then the `Insert Button` window shows.

Comment: Can you update you post with a bit more information? [1] What version of Netbeans? [2] What is the precise situation in which this occurs? (e.g. Is it only when you edit a specific type of file? How many times do you have to press tab? etc...)

Comment: Yes it's annoying. I am also wondering how to resolve this problem. This window pops up while typing HTML (in PHP files also it shows up when you try to write HTML). @skomisa

Comment: @Shashanth I posted a possible solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't replicate your problem with NetBeans 8.2, but I can make that **Insert Button** window appear by doing the following:

- Edit an HTML file.
- Press *control/space* to open the autocomplete menu as shown in the OP.
- Hit *enter*, which selects the first entry on the dropdown menu, which happens to be **Button**.
- The **Insert Button** window opens.

A second way of making that happen is:

- Edit an HTML file.
- Type **`<`** to open the drop down menu of all HTML tags.
- Press *backspace* to switch to the menu in the OP screenshot.
- Hit *enter*, which selects the first entry on the dropdown menu, which happens to be **Button**.
- The **Insert Button** window opens.

In the second scenario the initial display of that drop down menu can be prevented:

- **Tools > Options > Editor > Code Completion**
- Select **HTML** as the **Language**.
- Uncheck **Auto Popup Completion Window**.
- Click **Apply** then click **OK**.

[image: autoCompleteOff]

The change is immediately effective, so typing **`<`** no longer triggers the display of the drop down menu. Since I can't replicate your problem it may not fix your issue, but it's worth trying. You can still request the drop down menu by pressing *control/space*.

Comment: actually this is not the solution

Comment: @UrbiJr why not ?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45148920/1441712) is the right answer:

> Simply go to Tools/Palette/Code Clips and remove everything from
>   Palette (all folders and items).